# How to implement number of unique views on a page function in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to get total number of unique views on a particular post/page in android. Every user has a unique authentication id so their view should be counted as one irrespective of the number of times they view that post. I am using firebase for my database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trick that is

Create a particular data table or sub-tree in the firebase-database for each user where user data is stored like a **name**  etc like that.

So make a new child here which can be named as ***views***  in that store each post unique key that user has interacted with and similar in the post sub-tree create ***count*** and ***views*** which contains integer which shows the number of people which have viewed the post and ***views*** contains the unique id of users who have watched that post.